# What is the grammatical term for with + N + present participle?

Tags: grammar

> The matter was resolved with both parties cooperating.

*With + N + present participle* is used to indicate that two events happened at the same time. What is the official grammatical term for this?

Comment: *With* + NP (here *both parties cooperating*) is a prepositional phrase.  *Both* is a determinative telling us which parties to consider, and *cooperating* is a present participle acting as a modifier describing the parties.  The parties' cooperation and the matter's resolution happened at the same time, but we understand that through the semantics of the statement, not the grammar.

Comment: I'd question your semantics here. The exact function/meaning of 'with' here is hard to pin down. I'd say there is a (part-?) causal link rather than an added remark (a comma would probably make a difference). _The matter was resolved [largely] as a result of both parties cooperating._ 'What with both parties cooperating, the matter was resolved.' becomes a near paraphrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a special participle construction with "with", and if you want a special name for it you have to invent one. I simply call it with-construction and define it as "with + noun +participle. The with-construction can be transformed into a subclause with an appropriate conjunction such as after, because, although according to the sense of subclause and main clause. Sometimes it can be transformed to a main clause and sometimes the with-construction fits into the sentence as adverbial sentence part.

This construction corresponds to a Latin ablative absolute. Latin: ablativus absolutus, a very frequent literary construction, frequent because lengthy subclauses could be shortened in an elegant way. Horror for pupils who learn Latin because they can't think in the Roman way: With Troy destroyed Aeneas headed for Italy.

The construction has a lot of variants. It can be used with present participle or past participle, "with" can be dropped, and when the participle is "being" being is mostly dropped.